# Best practice for Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, openid-connect, okta

Can you suggest which Spring Security should I use to secure a real world Spring Boot Application, say for example banking application, where no social media login is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Bcrypt means you gonna have your own user database, which is a completely different thing from an external IdP. You'll have to take care of user registration, self-service, MFA and many other things.

External IdPs are more or less similar, one word though... If you are hosting your app inside one of big clouds, then check if you can harness their user pools (for AWS it's Cognito, as an example). From one perspective it makes you vendor locked, but opens other doors for using their internal services with a proper IAM in mind.

If you go with a completely external one, then they all should be pretty similar functionality-wise. Okta, Auth0 are some which I had experience with, but doesn't mean there are no other ones.

As for a protocol, no preference, though OIDC is pretty well supported by vendors and third parties. SAML sometimes is considered bit outdated, though is completely reliable and bullet proof. If your app will be calling some other services, then OIDC seems more natural way to go, as you will have to go with OAuth (I suppose) to call external providers.

Bottom line: decide if you are up to taking all the burden, mentioned in the first paragraph, onto your shoulders. If no desire -> go with an external one (I'd recommend that, but you'll have to pay for that, of course).

Comment: In okta, is the user logging in with the same credentials for different websites?.. Suppose, I have an ecommerce website and there is another banking website which too uses okta, then does the customer login with the same credentials, if they have created an okta account before?

Comment: if both apps are integrated with the same Okta tenant, then it's the same credentials. But if they are using different tenants then ...

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from your question:

> Should I go for Bcrypt / OATH 2.0 / OIDC/ Okta / any other?..

They way your question is formulated, brings a notion that you don't clearly understand about these tools, protocols or products in detail and that is perfectly fine my friend, Security is another jungle that we must venture.

Unfortunately there are no easy answers to this question. Security is important and we must pay attention on how we want to secure our apps and there are multiple layers to secure, underestimating or belittling this subject can be very dangerous and costly down the road.

My suggestions:

- Start learning the subject more intense and patiently because it is wide subject to be covered
- Consult with the experts, companies like Okta, Auth0, Keycloak (Community) has amazing people whom has created best product to ease our hardships in this matter, so by using their product and get their support should guarantee that your apps follow the best security practices out there so we can be more confident about our apps security, cheers.

Comment: Yeah..I actually quite didn't get the concept of okta. In okta, is the user logging in with the same credentials for different websites?.. Suppose, I have an ecommerce website and there is another banking website which too uses okta, then does the customer login with the same credentials, if they have created an okta account before?

Comment: No worries friend, I think you should raise a new question for that use case scenario

Answer (score 1):

Im just going to add to the above answer.

You are asking us experts what you should go for to secure your application and then you are asking:

> Bcrypt / OATH 2.0 / OIDC/ Okta / any other

If i would transfer this question into something else it would be:

> What would i use to hammer in this nail? a rock, an opinion, a paper, a weather phenomenon

So as you can see, you are comparing things that make no sense. So lets break it down a bit on a high level.

**BCrypt**

Is an encryption algorithm for encrypting data. Will it secure your application? on its own? no. Can it be a part of securing your application. Well yes (encrypting passwords etc)

**OAUTH 2.0**

Is a specification that defines a bunch of different login flows. Could it help securing your application? yes, if you choose to implement one of the oauth 2.0 flows.

**OIDC**

If OAUTH 2.0 defines the flows (the requests and responses) OIDC (Open ID Connect) is a specification that defines what should be in the requests and responses. What should be sent in each request and response. So a specification telling you what your classes should look like and what parameters that should exist. Will it help you? well if you choose to implement OAUTH 2.0 and want to send structured requests and responses, then sure.

**Okta**

A product that you can buy, that implements the 2 earlier described specifications. So if you want to talk to okta then you should implement one of the OAUTH 2.0 flows, using OIDC request and responses and send those to Okta.

So now when i have described what you are trying to compare i hope you understand that what you have described can't be compared because they are ALL completely different things.

You can't compare a dog to an airplane.

All things have their usages, so i would suggest you do more research. And im not saying that to be rude.